# Get node attributes of connected neightbouring nodes

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I am pretty new to networkx and working with graphs. Currently, I am working with a twitter dataset and I'm trying to get the attributes of any nodes that may be following a particular node. The approach I'm thinking of is to loop through all the nodes in my graph and use `in_edges()` to try and create a subgraph of the current node and all of its "followers" so that I can extract the attributes of those nodes which are following the target node. Unfortunately i'm not sure how to proceed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from studying this example:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(10,2))
G = nx.Graph([(1,0), (2,1), (3,2), (4,3), (5,1), (6,2), (7,6), (8,7), (9,0), (10,0), (11,10)])
blue_edges = dict.fromkeys(G.edges(1), 'blue') #dict of green edges
light_edges = dict.fromkeys(G.edges, 'lightblue')
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, light_edges, 'color')
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, blue_edges, 'color')
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, edge_color=nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'color').values())
```

[image]

I've used a quite rare method `dict.fromkeys(G.edges(1), 'blue')` to create a dictionary with blue values for all edges incident to node 1. You might like to move further with your question from this point:

```
>>> G.edges(1)
EdgeDataView([(1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 5)])
>>> list(G.edges(1))
[(1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 5)]
>>> [y for x,y in list(G.edges(1))]
[0, 2, 5]
```

Or you could simply do:

```
>>> list(G[1])
[0, 2, 5]
>>> list(G.adj[1])
[0, 2, 5]
```

And if you need a subgraph:

```
>>> G.subgraph([1] + G[1])
<networkx.classes.graph.Graph at 0x22a1ba6bb50>
>>> G.subgraph([1] + G[1]).nodes()
NodeView((0, 1, 2, 5))
>>> G.subgraph([1] + list(G[1])).edges()
EdgeView([(0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 5)])
```

Comment: Hi mathfux. I've managed to get the nodes I needed using the ```predecessors```  function in networkx the only problem is now i cant access the specific attribute of the node

Comment: @eeno Try: `nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'attr')[node_id]`

Comment: I've tried that and ```G.nodes[node]['attrib']``` but i keep getting a ```KeyError```. any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out the node attributes were set to a different graph.